# write a shell script to find the count of employees working in a given department name. (UNIX)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Find a number of employees in a given department.

```
EmpID|Name|Department
1|John|IT
2|Jack|IT
3|Kevin|Sales
4|Daniel|HR
5|Sam|Sales
```

output for department IT will give answer as

```
2
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

It's literally just grep with count parameter.

```
grep -c "IT" file_with_employees.txt
```

Comment: Problem with this approach: if you have a "Mr. KITTEN", working for the sales department, he will be counted too :-)

Comment: You're right. In this particular format and task, it could be avoided by grepping `"IT$"` (meaning IT followed by end-of-line). ;-)